# Trouble finding race condition in locking code with atomics & futexes

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, locking, atomic

I'm having a horrible time trying to debug a race-condition-causing-deadlock in my Linux-futex & atomic-ops based locking primitives. Here's the code I'm working with (exact same logic as the real code, just pulled out the dependency on data structures that aren't relevant to the problem):

```
int readers, writer, waiting;

void wrlock()
{
    int cur;
    while (atomic_swap(&writer, 1)) spin();
    while ((cur=readers)) futex_wait(&readers, cur);
}

void wrunlock()
{
    atomic_store(&writer, 0);
    if (waiting) futex_wake(&writer, ALL);
}

void rdlock()
{
    atomic_inc(&waiting);
    for (;;) {
        atomic_inc(&readers);
        if (!writer) return;
        atomic_dec(&readers);
        futex_wait(&writer, 1);
    }
}

void rdunlock()
{
    atomic_dec(&waiting);
    atomic_dec(&readers);
    if (writer) futex_wake(&readers, ALL);
}
```

The `atomic_*` and `spin` functions are pretty obvious. Linux futex ops are `futex_wait(int *mem, int val)` and `futex_wake(int *mem, int how_many_to_wake)`.

The deadlock condition I'm running into is 3 threads, `readers==0`, `writer==1`, `waiting==2`, and all threads waiting on `futex_wait`. I don't see how this can happen.

And for everyone who wants to yell at me for not using pthread primitives, please save it for another question. This is low-level code which operates without dependence on glibc/libpthread. In any case I think the question is probably useful to others for learning about low-level concurrency black magic, or maybe to scare anyone else away from trying to write code like this... ;-)

By the way, the hardware is x86, so even if there are memory-ordering issues with the code, I don't think they'd manifest as bugs. I'm guessing there's just a subtle misuse of futexes I'm missing, especially since the code works fine when all the waits are dummied out as spins.

Here's the generated asm for `wrlock` (basically identical to the version I posted except it's calling a separate function `lock` for the first spinlock). The additional conditional return at the beginning is "if we're not running multiple threads, bail out". `0x338` and `0x33c` correspond to `readers` and `writer`. `call 1af` is actually a relocation to call `futex_wait` which is external.

```
00000184 <wrlock>:
 184:   a1 18 00 00 00          mov    0x18,%eax
 189:   55                      push   %ebp
 18a:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 18c:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 18e:   75 02                   jne    192 <wrlock+0xe>
 190:   c9                      leave
 191:   c3                      ret
 192:   68 3c 03 00 00          push   $0x33c
 197:   e8 7e fe ff ff          call   1a <lock>
 19c:   58                      pop    %eax
 19d:   a1 38 03 00 00          mov    0x338,%eax
 1a2:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 1a4:   74 ea                   je     190 <wrlock+0xc>
 1a6:   6a 01                   push   $0x1
 1a8:   50                      push   %eax
 1a9:   68 38 03 00 00          push   $0x338
 1ae:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1af <wrlock+0x2b>
 1b3:   a1 38 03 00 00          mov    0x338,%eax
 1b8:   83 c4 0c                add    $0xc,%esp
 1bb:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 1bd:   75 e7                   jne    1a6 <wrlock+0x22>
 1bf:   eb cf                   jmp    190 <wrlock+0xc>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this illustrates your potential deadlock. Assume a single processor executing your 3 threads in the following sequence:

```
// to start, 
//   readers == 0, writer == 0, waiting == 0

Reader1
===================================

// in rdlock()
    atomic_inc(&waiting);
    for (;;) {
        atomic_inc(&readers);

    // if (!writer) has not been executed yet

    //   readers == 1, writer == 0, waiting == 1

writer 
===================================
// in wrlock()
while (atomic_swap(&writer, 1)) spin();
    while ((cur=readers)) futex_wait(&readers, cur)

    // writer thread is waiting

    // readers == 1, writer == 1, waiting == 1
    //   cur == 1



Reader1
===================================

// back to where it was in rdlock()
        if (!writer) return;
        atomic_dec(&readers);
        futex_wait(&writer, 1);

    // Reader1 is waiting
    //   readers == 0, writer == 1, waiting == 1

Reader2
===================================

// in rdlock()
    atomic_inc(&waiting);
    for (;;) {
        atomic_inc(&readers);
        if (!writer) return;
        atomic_dec(&readers);
        futex_wait(&writer, 1);

    // Reader2 is waiting
    //  readers == 0, writer == 1, waiting == 2
```

Now you're deadlocked.

Of course, I might not be understanding how the futex API works (I've never used them), so let me know if I'm off base here.  I assume that a `futex_wait()` that blocks (because the expected value was correct) will not unblock until there's a `futex_wake()` call for that address.

If `atomic_xxx()` operations can unblock a `futex_wait()`, this analysis is incorrect.

Finally, if this is what's happening to you, I haven't had a chance to think about possible solutions...

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Fixing it was easy - just add an extra wake after the `atomic_dec` in the loop in `rdlock`. It may be redundant, but it only happens on contention anyway so I don't care so much.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a memory ordering issue.  I don't know the x86 memory model that well, but I strongly suspect you need a memory fence around your `futex_*` calls.  I understand that x86 guarantees that one core will update the memory contents of other cores in the same order as memory cells are written, but it seems that you are relying on a stronger assumption - that the writes on one core would be immediately visible to others.  For example, say that core A has a `rdlock` and has just execute `rdunlock`.  Now, it clears both `waiting` and `readers`, but this information hasn't made it to core B by the time core B attempts `wrlock`.  Core B successfully acquires `writer`, but sees that there are extant `readers`.  The update to `writer` has not posted to core A by the point at which `rdunlock` checks if it needs to `futex_wake(&readers)`, so it does not.  This could exhibit your symptoms, and it would also have the property that it would recover if the `futex_*` calls were replaced by simple spins.  Does this make sense to you?

<strike>Hmm, `while ((cur=readers)) futex_wait(&readers, cur);` should be while `((cur==readers))...` ?</strike>

Comment: Nope. That's why I put it in extra parentheses, to silence the gcc warning. The idea is to load the value of `readers`, test it (as the while condition), and then pass that value to `futex_wait`. I can't read it again or the value might have changed.

Comment: I should probably declare the variables volatile for those semantics, but the generated asm is doing things right anyway so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Right, should have noticed the doucle-parens.

Comment: The only writes to any of these variables are via the `atomic_*` functions, which are implemented in the obvious way with the x86 `lock` prefix. This should assure their their effects are visible on other cpus/cores, no?

Comment: @R: could you post the generated assembly for `wrlock()`?

Comment: Posted. Did you want to see the spinlock too?